# Group by id(not primary key) with multiple type of addresses

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

My Address Table looks like this:

```
AddressID Street        City         AddressTypeID    PersonID
1         1st 2ave      Edmonton     1                10
2         3st 6ave      Edmonton     2                10
3         8st 5ave      Edmonton     5                10
4         7st 4ave      Edmonton     2                11
5         2st 9ave      Edmonton     3                12
6         9st 2ave      Edmonton     5                12
```

In that table the personid 10 has 3 different type of addresses.
I would like the result is group by personID which has the priority of addressTypeID 1, if the person doesn't has addresstypeID 1 then use addresstypeID 5

I would like the output looks like this:

```
AddressID Street        City         AddressTypeID    PersonID
1         1st 2ave      Edmonton     1                10
4         7st 4ave      Edmonton     2                11
6         9st 2ave      Edmonton     5                12
```

Thank you for answering my question

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: If you map AddressTypeID = 1 to `1`, AddressTypeID = 5 to `2` and AddressTypeID = 2 to `NULL` this is just another variant of the greatest-n-per-group problem. Unfortunately I don't know how that is done in MSSQL. ;)

Comment: What is the logic for PersonID 11? He has neither 1 nor 5. Is it possible for one person to have both `AddressTypeID` 2 and 3 but not 1 or 5? Do you have a specific order of preference for all possible `AddressTypeID` values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easiest not as a group by but by using the `row_number()` function:

```
select a.*
from (select a.*,
             row_number() over (partition by personId
                                order by (case when AddressTypeId = 1 then 1
                                               when AddressTYpeId = 5 then 2
                                               else 3
                                          end)
                               ) as seqnum
      from addresses a
     ) a
where seqnum = 1
```

Notice that I use a `case` statement in the `order by` clause to specify your priority level.

Answer (score 4):

```
; with cte as (
    select 
        a.AddressID, a.Street, a.City, a.AddressTypeID, a.PersonID,
        row_number() over(
            partition by a.PersonID 
            order by case a.AddressTypeID
                when 1 then 1
                when 5 then 2
                else 3
            end
        ) as rn
    from address a
)
select *
from cte
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
SELECT AddressTable.* FROM AddressTable INNER JOIN 

(SELECT PersonID, MIN(AddressID) as MinAddressID GROUP BY PersonID) AS MinIdTable ON 

AddressTable.AddressID = MinIdTable.MinIdTable
```

Comment: The fallback order was 1 then 5 and never 2.

Answer (score 0):

First, filter the table to include only the rows with AddressTypeID as 1 or 5, via subquery.  Then select the single one per person with the lowest AddressTypeID (since you want 1 to have priority over 5)

```
select 
    *
from
    (select * from myaddresstable 
    where AddressTypeID in (1, 5))
where
    row_number() over (partition by PersonID order by AddressTypeID asc) = 1
```